# Luigi - Pass a var as an output between tasks

Tags: python, var, luigi

I know I can pass vars between tasks by saving them to a file and then reading it in the next task. However I don't want to generate so many documents on my project, so I'm trying to pass it directly as a variable.

My code looks like this:

```
class FilterSpam(luigi.Task):
    time_slice = luigi.parameter.DateMinuteParameter(interval=30, default=datetime.datetime.today())

    filtered_tweets = []

    def requires(self):
        return Streaming(time_slice=self.time_slice)

    def run(self):
        with self.input().open('r') as infile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(infile, delimiter='\t')
            tweets = list(reader)
            self.filtered_tweets, spam = filter_spam(tweets, 0.7)

        with open('data/results/detected_spam.txt', 'a') as spam_file:
            for tweet in spam:    
                spam_json = json.dumps(tweet, ensure_ascii=False)
                spam_file.write(spam_json+'\n')

    def output(self):
        return self.filtered_tweets

class LemmatizeTweets(luigi.Task):
    time_slice = luigi.parameter.DateMinuteParameter(interval=30, default=datetime.datetime.today())

    def requires(self):
        return FilterSpam(time_slice=self.time_slice)

    def run():
        filtered_tweets = self.input() # Lista de diccionarios

        lemmatized_tweets = lemmatize(filtered_tweets)

        with self.output().open('w') as outfile:
            for tweet in lemmatized_tweets:
                tweet_json = json.dumps(tweet, ensure_ascii=False)
                outfile.write(tweet_json+'\n')

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('data/processed/{}.csv'.format(self.time_slice))
```

where `filtered_tweets` is a list of dicts.

Is it possible to pass this var to the task `LemmatizeTweets` without having to save it to a file? If not, what would be the best way to save the values? In a pickle, a .txt with a json object in each line...?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Not exactly. I was advised to do all the changes in the same task. For example, a joined my "FilterSpam" task and "LemmatizeTweets" in a single task called "ProcessTweets" which performed both operations and then saved results to a file. I don't know if this will be helpful for you, what are you exactly tryng to do?